# Eclipse RCP - ILazyTreeContentProvider implementation is unexpectedly eager

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application, and am trying to use a `ILazyTreeContentProvider` implementation in order to show only the visible items at a certain time.

The code:

Inside the class extending ViewPart:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        viewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.VIRTUAL);
        drillDownAdapter = new DrillDownAdapter(viewer);
        viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
        viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
        //viewer.setSorter(new NameSorter());
        viewer.setInput(getViewSite());

        // Create the help context id for the viewer's control
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(viewer.getControl(), "test.provider.lazy.viewer");
        makeActions();
        hookContextMenu();
        hookDoubleClickAction();
        contributeToActionBars();
    }
```

Inside the ContentProvider:

```
@Override
        public void updateElement(Object parent, int index) {
            System.out.println(updateElementCounter++);
            if (parent.equals(getViewSite())) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    TreeParent child = new TreeParent("Parent 1");
                    viewer.replace(parent, index, child);
                    viewer.setHasChildren(child, true);
                } else {
                    TreeParent child = new TreeParent("Parent 2");
                    viewer.replace(parent, index, child);
                    viewer.setHasChildren(child, true);
                    //viewer.setChildCount(child, 1);
                }
            } else {
                if (parent instanceof TreeParent) {
                    TreeParent treeParent = (TreeParent) parent;
                    if (treeParent.getName().equals("Parent 1")) {
                    TreeObject child = new TreeObject("Leaf "+index);
                    viewer.replace(treeParent, index, child);
                    viewer.setHasChildren(child, false);
                    //viewer.setChildCount(child, 0);
                    } else {
                        TreeObject child = new TreeObject("Special One");
                        viewer.replace(treeParent, index, child);
                        viewer.setHasChildren(child, false);
                        //viewer.setChildCount(child,0);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void updateChildCount(Object element, int currentChildCount) {
            if (element.equals(getViewSite())) {
                viewer.setChildCount(getViewSite(), 2);
            } else 
            if (element instanceof TreeParent) {
                TreeParent parent = (TreeParent) element;
                if (parent.getName().equals("Root")) {
                    viewer.setChildCount(parent, 2);
                } else if (parent.getName().equals("Parent 1")) {
                    viewer.setChildCount(parent, 20);
                } else {
                    viewer.setChildCount(parent, 1);
                }
            } else {
                viewer.setChildCount(element, 0);
            }

        }
```

The problem is that each time I expand the children of a TreeItem, it loads all the subelements, not just the visible ones, whereas the `System.out.println(updateElementCounter++);` command prints out all 22 despite having only 7 Tree Items visible.

[image]

Shouldn't the `ILazyTreeContentProvider` only load the ones that are visible? (In this case it's 7 items)

I must be doing something wrong...

Anyways, any opinions are very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have compared my example with [this one](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet047VirtualLazyTreeViewer.java?id=R4_3)
And I've found only one difference that made all the difference:

```
v.setUseHashlookup(true); //v is the TreeViewer
```

What the method states in its doc:

> Configures whether this structured viewer uses an internal hash table
>   to speeds up the mapping between elements and SWT items. This must be
>   called before the viewer is given an input (via setInput).

Now the content provider is actually lazy. Only paints the visible items, not ALL of them.